# Limit of product of elements of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given sequence $a_n = \sqrt[n]{(\frac{2012}{2013})^n - (\frac{2011}{2012})^n}$ and $A_n$ such $A_1 = 17$, $A_{n+1} = A_n \cdot a_n$. I have to examine limit of $A_n$. $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n= \frac{2012}{2013}$ and $A_{n+1} = a_1 \cdot a_2 ... a_n \cdot 17$ but I don't know anything about limit of $A_n$. Any hints?

Comment: Maybe you should consider acceptance answer? In old questions too, as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

You have already figured out $a_n \to \dfrac{2012}{2013}$, this says that $\exists N$ such that for any $n > N$, $$a_n < \dfrac{2012.5}{2013}$$

Then $A_n \leq A_N \left(\dfrac{2012.5}{2013}\right)^{n-N} \to 0$